# iOS 7 crashes BAD_ACCESS when using UIImagePickerController

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, ios7

I am trying to use a UIImagePickerController to let my users select  photos or take photos to be used in my app. But the app seems to crash most of the time whenever a image is selected from their photos or when they choose to use a photo taken. I used NSZombie objects and I get this message:

> [NSISRestrictedToNonNegativeVariable retain]: message sent to deallocated instance 0x168c3530

I don't know what is going on here. This same problem occurred when I was presenting a modal view occasionally.

Here is my code for presenting the UIImagePickerController and handling the response:

```
- (void)actionSheet:(UIActionSheet *)actionSheet didDismissWithButtonIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex
    {
        if ([[actionSheet buttonTitleAtIndex:buttonIndex] isEqualToString:CANCEL_TITLE]) {
            return;
        }
        UIImagePickerControllerSourceType sourceType = buttonIndex == 0 ? UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary : UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera;
        UIImagePickerController* controller = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
        controller.sourceType = sourceType;
        [controller setDelegate:self];
        if (buttonIndex == 1) {
            //PNCoverOverlayView* overlayView = [PNCoverOverlayView viewWithNibNamed:nil];
            //[controller setCameraOverlayView:overlayView];
            [controller setShowsCameraControls:YES];
        }
        [self presentViewController:controller animated:YES completion:nil];
    }

- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info
    {
        [picker dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:^{
            UIImage* originalImage = info[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage];
            _imageToUpload = originalImage;
            CGFloat scaleAdjust = ([[UIScreen mainScreen] respondsToSelector:@selector(scale)] && [[UIScreen mainScreen] scale] == 2) ? 0.5 : 1;
            CGFloat length = LENGTH * scaleAdjust;
            if ([picker sourceType] == UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera) {
                PNCoverOverlayView* overlay = (PNCoverOverlayView*)[picker cameraOverlayView];
                CGSize overlaySize = [overlay frame].size;
                UIImage* cropped = [UIImage imageCroppedToSize:overlaySize fromImage:originalImage];
                _imageToUpload =[UIImage imageResizedToSize:CGSizeMake(length, length) fromImage:cropped];
            } else {
                _imageToUpload = [UIImage imageScaledToMaximumLength:length fromImage:originalImage];
            }
            [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"reviewPhotoUpload" sender:self];
        }];
    }
```

I commented out adding a custom overlay to the UIImagePickerController, because that fixed the app crashing when presenting the UIImagePickerController

Comment: Is your problem resolved ?

Comment: No. My problem is not resolved

Comment: Experiencing the same issue, still found no ways to resolve this.

Answer (score 0):

You should check for the following things:

> 1. Are you testing it on device ?
> 2. Follow the steps mentioned under `Overview` in [this](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIImagePickerController_Class/UIImagePickerController/UIImagePickerController.html) apple guideline, and take care of the device on which you are running. e.g.,
>      iPhone or iPad.
> 3. Check for [isSourceTypeAvailable](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIImagePickerController_Class/UIImagePickerController/UIImagePickerController.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/UIImagePickerController/isSourceTypeAvailable:) also.
> 4. Also, Check for [isCameraDeviceAvailable](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIImagePickerController_Class/UIImagePickerController/UIImagePickerController.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/UIImagePickerController/isCameraDeviceAvailable:) property.
> 5. When trying to get [cameraOverlayView](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIImagePickerController_Class/UIImagePickerController/UIImagePickerController.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIImagePickerController/cameraOverlayView), you should check if its not `nil`. See the documentation of this property for more
>      information.

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

You are instantiating the controller in your function:

`UIImagePickerController* controller = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];`

You should keep a strong reference to the controller in your class, an ivar would be a good choice for that.

Comment: You don't really need to keep a strong reference as you present the controller right away and gets retained by the `presentingController` as long as it is not dismissed. All picker callbacks are made before being dismissed too.